# Speaker producing buzzing noise like tearing on ubuntu 14.04, Lenovo Y500

Tags: ubuntu, audio, speakers

I am using a dual boot win 10 and Ubuntu 14.04

My speaker works fine on Win 10 but produces buzzing/tearing sound always on Ubuntu.

However My headphones work fine with Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What sound drivers and software are you using on each OS?  What is the computer hardware?  Is the sound software the only thing running on each OS, or what other software runs concurrently (or in the background), on each OS?